Resolving Many-to-Many relationship for DTO-response object
These are my entities:
@Table
public record Movie(@Id Long id,
                    String title,
                    Set<DirectorRef> directors,
                    int releaseYear,
                    Genre genre,
                    Status status,
                    Instant createdAt,
                    Instant modifiedAt

) {
    public void addDirector(Director director) {
        this.directors.add(new DirectorRef(AggregateReference.to(director.id())));
    }
}

@Table
public record Director(@Id Long id,
                       String firstName,
                       String lastName,
                       @With LocalDate dob) {
}

@Table
public record DirectorRef(AggregateReference<Director, Integer> director) {
}

So there is a many-to-many-relationship between Movie and Director. I now want to implement a REST-Endpoint with a MovieResponse object that contains the Set of directors for the requested movie.
The response object currently looks like this:
package org.example.movieapi.movies;

import org.example.movieapi.directors.Director;

import java.util.Set;

public record MoviesResponse(Integer id,
                             String title,
                             Set<Director> directors,
                             int releaseYear,
                             Genre genre,
                             Status status
) {
}

How can I implement the resolution of the many-to-many relation between the two aggregates in an efficient manner? I was thinking about utlizing a Custom query like this:
@Repository
interface MovieRepository extends ListCrudRepository<Movie, Integer>, PagingAndSortingRepository<Movie, Integer> {

    @Query("""
                    SELECT id, title, release_year, genre, status 
                    FROM movie m
                    LEFT JOIN directorRef dRef 
                    ON m.id = dRef.movie
                    LEFT JOIN director d
                    ON dRef.director = d.id
                    WHERE (:title IS NULL OR title = :title)
                    AND (:releaseYear IS NULL OR release_year = :releaseYear)
                    AND (:genre IS NULL OR genre = :genre)
                    AND (:status IS NULL OR status = :status)
            """)
    List<MoviesResponseRaw> findAllMoviesByPredicates(
            String title,
            Integer releaseYear,
            Genre genre,
            Status status
    );
}

Where MoviesResponseRaw would be another data structure that corresponds to the result set of the query. Then I would have to manually group the result by movies and create the set of directors belonging to each queried movie in the service layer. To me that feels rather tedious and wrong so I suspect I am still missing some elementary conecpts in my understanding of Spring Data JDBC.
